# Count the no of keys in appconfig in a class file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, app-config, configuration-files

I need to know how to count the no of keys in app settings and manipulate through them in class file...
For example I'll have my app config as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Mysqlrateteller" value="server=localhost;Database=rateteller;User Id=root;Password=;"/>
    <add key="Mysqlrateteller1" value="server=localhost;Database=rateteller1;User Id=root;Password=;"/>
    <add key="Mysqlrateteller2" value="server=localhost;Database=rate;User Id=root;Password=;"/>
  </appSettings>

<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

Here i may have n no of keys. And i need to count the no of keys available in a class file of this project. how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
 var appSettings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
 int cntAppSettingKeys = appSettings.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

[AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) is a **[NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx)**. So below code will work

```
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Count
```